# Bash: how would you extract all the lines between two sentences?

Tags: bash, sed, terminal

I have a file like this:

```
When, in the course of human events, 
it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve 
*** Start copy here ***
the political bonds which have connected them 
with another, and to assume among the powers of 
*** End copy here ***
the earth, the separate and equal station to 
which the laws of nature and of nature's God entitle them
```

and I want to write a one line terminal command to extract the lines between `*** Start copy here ***` and `*** End copy here ***` so the output should be:

```
the political bonds which have connected them 
with another, and to assume among the powers of
```

How would I do this? I don't want to use `awk` (I've been playing around with `sed` but can't get it right) and the other responses I've found find words rather than sentences, which confuses me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '/*** End copy here ***/{flag="";next}/*** Start copy here ***/{flag=1;next} flag'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to do the same using `sed` instead of `awk`?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '1,/^\*\*\* Start copy here \*\*\*$/d' -e '/^\*\*\* End copy here \*\*\*$/,$d' tmp.txt
```